# "plot.new" error when checking normality of residuals using qqline()

Tags: r, plot, regression, linear-regression, lm

I would like to check if my model (standardized) residuals are normally distributed.

```
model <- lm(ratiopermonth ~ Greenspace, data = mydata)
qqline(rstandard(model))
```

But I got an error message:

```
plot.new has not been called yet
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`qqline` is to be used after `qqnorm`.

```
r <- rstandard(model)
qqnorm(r)
qqline(r)
```